# multiple use of javascript function for different dynamic css Ids

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, razor

I have a `UI FRM` page where users can add as many New sections as much as they want
and also inside those sections, he can add many resources he wants
and also he can change the order of resources using the up and down arrow keys for that
I have written a javascript function for the up and down arrow key
the problem is that every time the user adds any new  section dynamically, a new `SectionId` is created `(for exa =SectionId_1 )`like  this
and the user can add as many sections as he wants so `(SectionId_1)` would be every time new I want to write such java script function for `fnUpOrderCustomResource`,`fnDownOrderCustomResource`  so that if I change the order of resources using up and down arrow key it identifies each section uniquely based on order length and it doesn't get confused.

```
<script>

    function fnUpOrderCustomResource(order) {
   
        if (order == 1) {
            //alert('You are at first position, you can not move up!');
            swal("", "You are at first position, you can not move up!", "warning");
            return false;
        }
        else if (order > 1) {
            var curr_order = order;
            var up_order = order - 1;

            var curr_element = $(".CustomResource .frmResources[data-order='" + curr_order + "']");
            
            var up_element = $(".CustomResource .frmResources[data-order='" + up_order + "']");
            
            curr_element.css("order", up_order);
            curr_element.attr("data-order", up_order);

            up_element.css("order", curr_order);
            up_element.attr("data-order", curr_order);

            curr_element.find(".uparrow").attr("onclick", 'fnUpOrderCustomResource(' + up_order + ')');
            curr_element.find(".downarrow").attr("onclick", 'fnDownOrderCustomResource(' + up_order + ')');
            
            

            up_element.find(".uparrow").attr("onclick", 'fnUpOrderCustomResource(' + curr_order + ')');
            up_element.find(".downarrow").attr("onclick", 'fnDownOrderCustomResource(' + curr_order + ')');
            
            
        }
    }

    function fnDownOrderCustomResource(order) {
        var order_length = $(".CustomResource .frmResources").length;

        if (order == order_length) {
            //alert('You are at last position, you can not move down!');
            swal("", "You are at last position, you can not move down!", "warning");
            return false;
        }
        else if (order < order_length) {
            var curr_order = order;
            var down_order = order + 1;

            var curr_element = $(".CustomResource .frmResources[data-order='" + curr_order + "']");
            var down_element = $(".CustomResource .frmResources[data-order='" + down_order + "']");
            curr_element.css("order", down_order);
            curr_element.attr("data-order", down_order);

            down_element.css("order", curr_order);
            down_element.attr("data-order", curr_order);

            curr_element.find(".uparrow").attr("onclick", 'fnUpOrderCustomResource(' + down_order + ')');
            curr_element.find(".downarrow").attr("onclick", 'fnDownOrderCustomResource(' + down_order + ')');

            down_element.find(".uparrow").attr("onclick", 'fnUpOrderCustomResource(' + curr_order + ')');
            down_element.find(".downarrow").attr("onclick", 'fnDownOrderCustomResource(' + curr_order + ')');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify Function Signatures

```
function fnUpOrderCustomResource(sectionId, order) {
    // Function body remains the same with adjustments for sectionId
}

function fnDownOrderCustomResource(sectionId, order) {
    // Function body remains the same with adjustments for sectionId
}
```

Update jQuery Selectors Inside both functions, replace

```
$(".CustomResource .frmResources[data-order='" + curr_order + "']");
```

with

```
$("#" + sectionId + " .frmResources[data-order='" + curr_order + "']");
```

And similarly for other selectors.

In the section where you update the `.uparrow` and `.downarrow onclick events`, include `sectionId` in the function call

```
curr_element.find(".uparrow").attr("onclick", 'fnUpOrderCustomResource(' + up_order + ')');
```

with

```
curr_element.find(".uparrow").attr("onclick", 'fnUpOrderCustomResource("' + sectionId + '", ' + up_order + ')');
```